# Rounded Rectangle with Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I'm attempting to draw a rectangle around a custom view in Android. I mostly have it working except for one detail.

Here is my code...

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setStrokeWidth(14.5f);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

canvas.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 20.0f, 20.0f, paint);
```

And here is the resulting rectangle...

[image]

As you can see, the inside of the rectangle does have rounded corners, but the outside still draws pointed corners. How can I make it so that the outside corners are rounded as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see corners rounded on the outside because part of the stroke is outside of the bounds of the `Canvas`. You can check this easily by adding a certain margin to the coordinates of the round rectangle to make sure it is drawn inside the `Canvas`.

In fact your best option is trying to optimize this margin depending on the selected stroke width.

Comment: You're right. If I add some padding to my bounds it's working as I would expect. Thank you!